# Problem loading MS Word docx file to Google Drive via .net nuget package API

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-drive-api

we cannot anderstand why we upload docx-file via Google Drive API v3, it compleete success. But after we upload docx we try open file and cannot open it, thre is error in error

[image]

But when open our disk in browser (Google Chrome) and  try upload docx again it opens fine, without any error.

Can you please tell what is wrong we made.

Code example

```
class Program
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadata };
    static string ApplicationName = "Drive API .NET Quickstart";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
            var clientSecrets = new ClientSecrets();
            clientSecrets.ClientId = "";
            clientSecrets.ClientSecret = "";
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                clientSecrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Drive API service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        // fileMetadata.Name = @"excel1.xlsx";
        fileMetadata.Name = @"word22222.docx";
        // fileMetadata.Name = @"present1.pptx";
        // var fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\temp\present.pptx", FileMode.Open);
        string fileId = string.Empty;
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\temp\word3.docx", FileMode.Open))
        {
            // var fileStream = File.Open(@"c:\temp\excel1.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
            var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            // var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
            fileUpload.Fields = "id";
            // var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
            // fileMetadata.MimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            // var fileUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            IUploadProgress progress = fileUpload.Upload();
            if (progress.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(progress.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                fileId = fileUpload.ResponseBody.Id;
                Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + fileUpload.ResponseBody.Id);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

        var permission = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.Permission();
        permission.Type = "anyone";
        permission.Role = "writer";
        permission.PermissionDetails = new List<PermissionDetailsData>();
        var perm = service.Permissions.Create(permission, fileId);
        perm.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Premission created!");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + fileId + "/edit");
        // Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + fileId + "/edit");
        // Process.Start("explorer.exe", "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/" + fileId + "/edit");
        Console.WriteLine("Redirected to browser!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: That problem only for MS Words docs, Presentetion or Excep uploading hav no problem

Comment: Are you using the very same code to upload `.ppt` and `.xlxs` files?

Comment: Yes. Absolutly the same. In example you see that I comment/uncoment only file names, mime types and google docs editing url.

Comment: Solve the problem, need convert docx to google doc format when upload it. More info in my another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63900473/1335582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Consideration

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#auth) and to my tests you cannot create a file with the `metadata` scope only.

Using this scope will result in a permission error. Please try to use a more restricted scope to perform this operation.

```
Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
```

### Solution

You can use one of these:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata

In C# this translates in one of these statements:

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
// OR
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata };
// OR
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
```

### Reference

[Drive Files Create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try all combination of scopes, but it still do not work, the same error when open word file for edit. In fiddler I found no errors.

Comment: It happens only with this particular docx then?

Comment: I try three word files and error was the same. Do you try my example? It works for you?

Comment: It is .net core 2.1 and nuget package Google.Apis.Drive.v3 Version="1.49.0.2030"

Comment: Your example doesn't work with any file format since the `metadata` scope has not enough permission to perform a file upload. Have you tried to delete the Access Token and repeat the authentication process?

Comment: I add all scopes
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
delete token.json file and  trye again. After I delete token.json, API redirect me to browser to grant access to selected scopes. After I grant access word file created and opened. THen I logout from google in browser and try create file again. Then problem still appear. May by my understand is wrong with token? It worked after I signout?

Comment: I'm glad it works now. If this answer was helpful for you please accept it so it can help other users too.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) is the documentation about OAuth2 in Google applications. Please read it carefully to understand how to use tokens.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not work for now. It work if I login in browser gmail or google drive. I need create files in google drive without opened browser, I need open create and open docs with access token.

Comment: This is how Client `access_token` works. If you want to bypass the user interaction/browser-login you will have to use a [service-account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). But this is another approach and you should open a new question.

Comment: Ok. I understand how it works. With service account the same problem. I will open new question.